# Compare columns from two different data frames and one column value

Tags: pandas

I have two different data frames named as df1 and df2.
df1 has columns date1 and value1.
df2 has date2 and val ( initially it contains 0).
The val column value from df2 need to update to 1 when matching date found in df1.

This one was achieved by looping both the data frames with two for loops,
As volume is very high,it is taking more time.
Is there any best way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
common = pd.np.intersect1d(df1.date1.values, df2.date2.values)
df2.loc[df2.date2.isin(common), 'val'] = 1
```